# How to create variables dynamiccally in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to create variables dynamically in javascript

eg

I have a loop

```
for (i=0;i<15;i++){
}
```

now I need to create variables dynamically eg var "a"+i for eavh value in the loop. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Can you just use an array? `var array = []; for (i=0;i<15;i++){array[i] = ...}`?

Comment: Array is the most suitable candidate here. It is unwise to use a lot of such variables in Javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are dealing with numeric, sequential variables — use an array.

```
var foo = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    foo[i] = something;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If we presume that you will need several variables related to each iteration ([foo1,bar1], [foo2, bar2]...) then there are two approaches

**Use arrays**

```
var foo = [], bar = [];
foo[1] = "foo"; 
bar[1] = "bar";
```

**Use an object**

```
var myVars = {};
myVars["foo" + 1] = "foo";
myVars["bar" + 1] = "bar";
```

That last one could also be written as

```
 myVars.bar1 = "bar";
```

Do **not** use `eval` as some has suggested.

Comment: @nemesisdesign I didn't say it was evil, just that it doesn't belong in this use case. `eval` is only 'evil' if used wrong, so don't listen to everything The Crock says..

Answer (score 4):

To fulfill your exact requirement, I know only `eval()`:

```
eval("varname"+i+" = 'Hello';");
```

on the other hand, you could consider using an array. Much cleaner: They don't clutter the global namespace, and you can order variables neatly in groups.

```
arrayname[i] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be unwise to pollute your namespace with such a large number of variables. Use an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the evil [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/Eval) function for this purpose:

```
for (var i=0; i < 15; i++){
    eval( 'var a' + i + ' = "something"' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`window` mostly represents the global object on browsers. You can use either that or scope it to your own objects.

```
var my = {};

for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    my["a" + i] = "value: " + i;
}

console.log(my.a4); // "value: 4"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using [array](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) instead of variables. `Array` has [`push`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) method which adds a new element to array.