# Creating a variable, with a variable in an each loop - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dynamic, each

I'm having some difficulty creating a variable with another variable in jQuery. I don't know how to write the var side of the equation. Here's what I'm trying to create:

```
var $counter= 0;
    $('.selector').each(function(){
       $counter += 1;
       var newVariable-($counter) // this is where I'd like to create the new  
                                  // variable with the number from $counter at the end.
    });
```

with the goal to creating:

```
newVariable-1
newVariable-2
newVariable-3...
```

and so on...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895930/how-to-create-variables-dynamiccally-in-javascript

Comment: Readability tip: Try to use variables beginning with `$` only for caching jQuery selections. (`var $counter = $('#counter'); var counter = 0;`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create an object to hold these values but not dynamic variables.

```
var $counter= 0;
var variableHolder = {};
$('.selector').each(function(){
   $counter += 1;
   variableHolder["newVariable-"+$counter] = ...
});
```

Or if you want to make global variables (which is not recommended), you could use `window`:

```
var $counter= 0;
$('.selector').each(function(){
   $counter += 1;
   window["newVariable-"+$counter] = ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, using an `{}` with [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) will simplify this task greatly.

Something like this:

```
var myobj = {},
    prefix = 'my_cool_var';

for(var i = 0, len = 10; i < len; i++) {
    myobj[prefix + i] = undefined; // { my_cool_var + i : undefined }
}

// Setters - dot notation and square bracket
myobj.my_cool_var1 = "Hello!";
myobj['my_cool_var2'] = "Hello 2!";

// Getters - dot notation and square bracket
alert(myobj.my_cool_var1); // alerts Hello!
alert(myobj['my_cool_var2']); // alerts Hello 2!
```

Now, if you needed to expose the variables in a global scope (yuck - but hey, sometimes you gotta) so you don't need to specify an object (`myobj`), you can use `window` with square bracket notation in your `for loop`.

```
var prefix = 'my_global_var';

for(var i = 0, len = 10; i < len; i++) {
    window[prefix + i] = undefined; // creates global, my_global_var + i = undefined
}

my_cool_var1 = "Hello!";
alert(my_cool_var1); // alerts Hello!
```

Finally, if you search the web deep enough, you'll find `eval` examples like this:

```
var prefix = 'my_evil_var';

for(var i = 0, len = 10; i < len; i++) {
    // Don't do this. Use square bracket notation with window, if you need a global.
    eval(prefix + i + '= undefined') // creates global, my_evil_var + i = undefined
}

my_evil_var = "Eval abuse is bad!!";
alert(my_evil_var1); // alerts Eval abuse is bad!!
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of the json in this context,

```
var $counter= 0;
var $newVar = {};

$('.selector').each(function(){
   $counter += 1;
   $newVar['newVariable-'+ ($counter)] = null;
});
```

so you can access it like `$newVar.newVariable-1`,.. `$newVar.newVariable-N`  And please note that this is the best practice, we could do as you asked by accessing the window object, but that is not recommended.